# PHP simpletest assertion

Tags: php, assertions

What is the equivalent of assertLessThan in simpletest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
assertTrue($x < 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`assertTrue`](http://www.simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/UnitTester/UnitTestCase.html#assertTrue):

```
assertTrue($x < $y);
```